# Matlab contourf

Tags: matlab

If I'm asked to plot a function S with "level lines" abs(S) = 0:0.1:1, how do I do that?

I looked up the solution:

```
  [X,Y] = meshgrid(-15:0.1:15);
  Z = X + i*Y;
  contourf(X,Y,abs(S),[1 1]);
```

where they pass in the fourth argument [1 1] but I've no idea what it's doing. Why do they pass in [1 1] if they ask me for lines between 0 and 1?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're making a mistake.

The [help to `contourf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contourf.html) states

> To draw a single contour of level i, use contour(Z,[i i])

So they're drawing a single contour line at 1.

You want to write

```
contourf(X,Y,abs(S),0:0.1:1);
```

because the help says

> contourf(Z,v) draws a filled contour
>   plot of matrix Z with contour lines at
>   the data values specified in the
>   monotonically increasing vector v. The
>   number of contour levels is equal to
>   length(v)